# Android - how to fetch data from Joomla 3.3 database

Tags: android, database, web-services, joomla

I've tried to understand how to fetch data from joomla database with android app but i didn't found what i was looking for. 
In the past i've used Joomla api to use joomla database with php custom pages.

Are there some API to use with android? or do i have to write some webservice and use them to make android and joomla DB interact? if this is the only way i have to follow, could you explain me what i have to do or where i could find a good guide to study how to write a good webservice to interact with joomla and how to read it ?

Thanks for the help!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to write a web service that exposes the Joomla data through an API. You need two things

1. Joomla server/service which would probably need some way of Authenticating the user which could be oAuth or preshared secret
2. Android client that will connect to the service, authenticate and consume the API and the data

You can check this library which allows you to build REST API on top of Joomla: https://github.com/techjoomla/com_api

Also if you don't need the Joomla functionality but just the data from the database you don't need to plugin your API in Joomla structure itself. Build a standalone REST API/service that will allow your Android app to connect directly without interfering with the Joomla website processes. Thus if you need to do some optimisations to the API or Joomla (e.g. upgrade) you don't need to take both down as they'll be loosely coupled.

For building a RESTful API with oAuth authentication you can go down many routes. One option would be using Laravel and oAuth server and a simple API that will plug in your database and generate JSON output.

**Laravel** - http://laravel.com/

**oAuth Server**

- https://github.com/lucadegasperi/oauth2-server-laravel
- https://github.com/thomaswelton/laravel-oauth

**REST API**

- https://github.com/dingo/api

pull those libraries together and you have a working service

On the Android side you have to build the client authentication and JSON parser to map it to your model classes:

**oAuth Client**

- https://github.com/wuman/android-oauth-client
- https://code.google.com/p/google-oauth-java-client/wiki/Setup
- http://nilvec.com/implementing-client-side-oauth-on-android.html

**JSON parser** - http://code.google.com/p/google-gson/

Comment: Thanks for the help !! :)  now i can understand better whati have to do and now i just have to study "How" to write down a rest service !